# Why does the root element in layout xml file have height and width as match_parent

Tags: java, android

When I create a new android project using eclipse for android developers, it generates all the files which includes the layout XML file. I checked the root element (LinearLayout) in it and its attributes are,

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

I am not able to understand what "match_parent" means for the root element. I did a little bit of digging and found out :

> For the root LinearLayout, the value of both the height and width
>   attributes is match_parent. The LinearLayout is the root element, but
>   it still has a parent – the view that Android provides for your app’s
>   view hierarchy to live in.

Can someone please explain what this means.

Comment: You have your own answer. When you have `match_parent` your LinearLayout will match the same height and width as the view that Android provides for your app's view hierarchy to live in.

Comment: I am not understanding - "but it still has a parent – the view that Android provides for your app’s view hierarchy to live in."

Comment: Yes, that View provided by the system is the parent for whatever view you create.

Comment: Basically, think of the parent as "all available space". Of course this excludes space taken up by the Action Bar, System Notification Bar, and (on devices that have them) the software buttons at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: ok... So the view provided by android is the entire canvas/screen except action bar**??.. and it is the parent of all root elements in layout files?...

Comment: Yeah. You'll never interact with it directly (that I know of) and your view in most cases should stay `match_parent` for both height and width.